# How to allow xml:lang attribute in XMLSchema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to allow the use of xml:lang attributes in some of my element of my XMLSchema. But i can't find anything which describes how to to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either create your own attribute with xmlschema type [language](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#language), or reference xml:lang attribute as in the example [Import another XML schema](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XML-Schema/importanotherXMLschema.htm). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

You have to do a bit of hunting to piece this together from the standards. Here's the magic sauce you need in order to allow `xml:lang` attributes on your XML elements.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <!-- Import xml: namespace -->
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
        schemaLocation="https://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd" />

  <!-- ... --->

  <xs:complexType name="myLanguagedElement">
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- use ref="" instead of name="", here in your attribute -->
    <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="optional" /><!-- or "required" if you like -->
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Edit:** The new schemaLocation changed to **https://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd**

Comment: How should it appear in a DTD to have this result through conversion?

Comment: @MrGadget I'm not sure how to do this with DTDs. The question here was about using schemas.