# How to declare an xml:lang attribute in an XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to declare an `xml:lang` attribute in XML Schema for the following sample instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xml-lang-1.xsd">
    <entry>
        <language xml:lang="en">
            <other_data/>
        </language>
        <language xml:lang="nl">
            <other_data/>
        </language>
    </entry> 
</database>
```

For the moment, I got two solutions:

1. Using:

   ```
   <xs:attributeGroup name="XMLNamespaceAttrs">
     <xs:anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" processContents="lax"/>
   </xs:attributeGroup>
   ```

within the same schema, or

2. Using `xs:import` and importing:

   ```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
      <xs:import schemaLocation="xml-lang-2.xsd"/>
      <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:NCName"/>
   </xs:schema>
   ```

from an external file.

My questions:

- Are there other ways to declare the xml:lang attribute in XML Schema?
- How can I associate a use attribute with the xml:lang attribute? In the examples above, the use attribute is not allowed with the
  xs:anyAttribute (solution 1) and the xs:attribute (solution 2).
- Is the data type for `xml:lang` in the examples above handeled implicitely as `xs:languag`e (or other) or needs this to be/can this be
  declared explicitely?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow xml:lang attribute in XMLSchema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502382/how-to-allow-xmllang-attribute-in-xmlschema)

Answer (score 0):

I think in the most efficient way to declare an attribute in the XML's namespace is the first option: first, declare your attribute in a different schema that has the XML's namespace as target namespace, then `import` this schema into your main schema and `ref` the attribute you want to use. This way you can use the `use` attribute along with your XML's schema attribute.